# Linq query gives me ambigious invocation error on the select statement

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm

building a query to return workflows that are in the waiting status and are related to a certain entity...

When I try to write the select statement in my linq query, I get the error "Ambigious invocation" on the select statement. I'm not sure exactly what it means. Here is my code, anyone have a hint or a point in the right direction?

```
                List<AsyncOperation> processes = (from p in orgSvcContext.AsyncOperationSet
                             where p.PrimaryEntityType == entityLogicalName
                                   && p.RegardingObjectId.Id == regardingObjectId
                                   && p.Name == processName
                                   && p.StatusCode.Value == 10 
                             select new AsyncOperation { Id = p.Id, StateCode = p.StateCode, StatusCode = p.StatusCode })
           .ToList();
```

[image: error]

Comment: It looks like `AsyncOperation` may be ambiguous which means that there are multiple definitions for it. Try writing out the fully qualified namespace for that and see if that clears it up. Maybe this: `select new System.ComponentModel.AsyncOperation` ... or which ever library it belongs to.

Comment: I gave that a go, just to make sure (it was part of System.ComponentModel.AsyncOperation btw) but I still get the error under the select statement. I added a screenshot to the error.

Comment: Will you please post the updated code that you used? It looks like there is an `AsyncOperation` in the `CrmEarlyBound` and `System.ComponentModel` libraries and it still can't tell which one to use...Also, have you extended the `System.ComponentModel.AsyncOperation` class to include a constructor? I am not seeing a constructor there...

Comment: Scratch that...it looks like the class is `sealed` so you wouldn't be able to derive from it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be, that there are two Select methods that are found. 
One in Queryable (Accepting a class deriving from IQueryable<>) and one in Enumerable (Accepting a class deriving from IEnumerable<>).

Your `orgSvcContext.AsyncOperationSet` seems to be implementing both Interfaces, which means the compiler doesn't know which one to choose.

You should be able to solve your problem by first calling AsEnumerable or AsQueryable on `orgSvcContext.AsyncOperationSet`, whatever suits you best.

This should look like this (Check the AsEnumerable on the first line):

```
            (from p in orgSvcContext.AsyncOperationSet.AsEnumerable()
             where p.PrimaryEntityType == entityLogicalName
                   && p.RegardingObjectId.Id == regardingObjectId
                   && p.Name == processName
                   && p.StatusCode.Value == 10 
             select new AsyncOperation { Id = p.Id, StateCode = p.StateCode, StatusCode = p.StatusCode })
```

Comment: always a pleasure, no problem :)

Comment: Hello, this also saved me some time.  There are other LINQ queries not specifying this, which are similar but they work.   not sure why that's happening but this did the trick.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using two namespace which implement a select method with the same arguments, so they are ambiguous.
Try to use the whole namespace

```
var a = System.Linq.Select(source);
```

or an alias on the namespaces

```
using LINQ = System.Linq;
...
var a = LINQ.Linq.Select(source);
```